# XML Schema Unique Keys

Tags: xml, schema, unique

I am admittedly new to Schema, and I am trying to get a particular attribute to be unique within a set. I also need this value to be a key, as it will be referenced elsewhere.

This is my current schema:

```
 <xs:element name="subroutines" type="guisubroutines_Type" minOccurs="1">

    <xs:key name="Subroutine_Key">
      <xs:selector xpath="subroutine"/>
      <xs:field xpath="@name"/>
    </xs:key>

    <xs:unique name="Subroutine_Unique">
      <xs:selector xpath="subroutine"/>
      <xs:field xpath="@name"/>
    </xs:unique>

  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="guisubroutines_Type" >
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="subroutine" type="subroutine_Type" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>        
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="subroutine_Type">
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>
```

This is my xml:

```
  <subroutines>
    <subroutine name="one"></subroutine>
    <subroutine name="one"></subroutine>
  </subroutines>
```

I am currently using Visual Studio 2010, and it says that this xml is valid, though it does throw a warning if the name is not there. I would like it to throw a warning if two names are the same.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4):

So I figured it out after looking here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/xmlandnetfx/thread/25603e1c-d7dd-48d2-a9f6-8d4177845441/

The quick answer is that you need to add the namespace to the xpath expression.
Not sure if this is a VS thing or just in general, but...

```
<xs:key name="Subroutine_Key">
   <xs:selector xpath="mstns:subroutine"/>
   <xs:field xpath="@name"/>
</xs:key>
```

Fixed the issues I was having.

Again thank you for your time, and I apologize for wasting it.